# PySpark- How to output csv/parquet file with the sequential records?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery

I'd plan to read data from a very large BigQuery table then output with 61,000 sequential records, I've tried code below:

```
TMP_BUCKET = "stg-gcs-bucket"
MAX_PARTITION_BYTES = str(512 * 1024 * 1024)
# 1k Account per file
# MAX_ROW_NUM_PER_FILE = "18300"
MAX_ROW_NUM_PER_FILE = "61000"

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master('yarn') \
    .appName('crs-bq-export-csv') \
    .config('spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled', 'true') \
    .config('spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.23.2.jar') \
    .config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "36000") \
    .config("spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile", MAX_ROW_NUM_PER_FILE) \
    .config("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", MAX_PARTITION_BYTES) \
    .config("spark.files.maxPartitionBytes", MAX_PARTITION_BYTES) \
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "24g") \
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true") \
    .getOrCreate()


#Try to read full data from BQ
df = spark.read.format('bigquery') \
    .option('table', TABLE_NAME) \
    .load()

df.sort('colA').sort('colB').write.mode('overwrite').csv(OUTPUT_PATH, header=True)
```

but the final results didn't sort with the colA and colB and they are all inordinate:
Expected CSV:

```
colA colB
1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
....
60001 60001
```

But got:

```
colA colB
2. 1
3. 3
2. 2
1. 3
```

I checked the spark doc and it will shullfle all dfs in order to get better performance, but I need to get the final csv with specific order, how can I achieve this?

How can I do for this case? Any helps will be super helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create the dataframe like this:

```
data = [("2.", "1"),

        ("3.", "3"),

        ("2.", "2"),

       ("1.", "3")]

columns = ["colA", "colB"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df.show()

+----+----+
|colA|colB|
+----+----+
|2.  |1   |
|3.  |3   |
|2.  |2   |
|1.  |3   |
+----+----+
```

If I run your code I get:

```
df.sort('colA').sort('colB').show()

+----+----+
|colA|colB|
+----+----+
|  2.|   1|
|  2.|   2|
|  1.|   3|
|  3.|   3|
+----+----+
```

Let's look at the execution plan it sorts by `colB`:

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Sort [colB#1 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
   +- Exchange rangepartitioning(colB#1 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=94]
      +- Scan ExistingRDD[colA#0,colB#1]
```

And that is in line with the way the sort function is implemented - it sorts the whole dataframe based on the column values from the columns you have passed to the sort function. So, the final effect of chaining sort function calls has means that the resulting dataframe will be sorted based on the last sort function call.

Here is the correct approach for your use case:

```
df.sort('colA', 'colB').show()
df.sort('colA', 'colB').explain()

+----+----+
|colA|colB|
+----+----+
|  1.|   3|
|  2.|   1|
|  2.|   2|
|  3.|   3|
+----+----+

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Sort [colA#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, colB#1 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
   +- Exchange rangepartitioning(colA#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, colB#1 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=148]
      +- Scan ExistingRDD[colA#0,colB#1]
```

As you can see in the output dataframe and in the execution plan, it sorts by both columns because I am passing both columns to the sort function, first by `colA` and then by `colB`.

Comment: Hi @ms12 thank you for your response, it works now, one more question, how can I control the target file location with specific data range (like id 1-600 to part001, 601-1200 to part002 etc)?